# Unity3D Как сделать, чтобы частицы не были плоскими?

Tags: c#, unity3d, particles

Я создал частицы огня. Однако поставил я его на центр, но частицы настолько плоские, что с боковых сторон не видно. Даже с обратной стороны.
Это понятно, ведь я в частицы вложил двумерную картину.
Я добавил ещё одну систему частиц, поменяв transform.rotation.y = 180, но он всё равно смотрит в ту же сторону. С обратной ни той, ни другой системы частиц не видно.
Как сделать так, чтобы частицы смотрели в разные стороны?

Comment: поверни сам объект(систему частиц). в самом верху, вкладка Transform

Comment: Я пробовал, ничего не меняется

Comment: Частицы **повёрнуты к камере**, как не крути объект. Кажется это настраивается в самой нижней вкладке отвечающей за рендер.

Comment: Первое, нужно отключить опцию, поворачивающую частицы в сторону камеры.
Второе, огонь -довольно сложная структура, одной частицы тут мало, нужно создать эмиттер и порождать частицы с разной угловой ориентацией вокруг вертикальной оси (если речь идет о костре), если речь идет о форсированном пламени, то тут все немного сложнее.